# What may the arguments be to Region (11.1)?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

In Mathematica version 11.1, there is a new function `Region`. While the Documentation Center page `ref/Region` has a number of examples, it fails to say exactly what arguments are allowed.

For example, while `Region[RegionUnion[Disk[], Disk[{2, 2}, 1]]]` works as expected, is it possible to make the 2nd disk a different color?

I am aware of [What is a "Region" in Mathematica 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/what-is-a-region-in-mathematica-10).